# Can you create custom build rules for XCode based on file type?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, makefile

I have a project with a bunch of .png files that I want to convert to PVRTC compressed textures.  Right now, I'm using a custom XCode run script phase that looks like this:

```
TEXTURE_TOOL=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool

$TEXTURE_TOOL -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o "$SRCROOT/images/select_menu_bgs1.pvr" -f PVR "$SRCROOT/images/select_menu_bgs1.png"
$TEXTURE_TOOL -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o "$SRCROOT/images/select_menu_bgs2.pvr" -f PVR "$SRCROOT/images/select_menu_bgs2.png"
```

but it's annoying to have to make it explicitly include the exact list of files I need converted.  (they also need to be added to the input & output properties of the build step, which is the even more annoying part.)

what I would like to do is something easy with "make": have a rule that says "if there's a .pvr in the project, it's built from the corresponding .png using this command line."

Is anything like this possible in XCode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-click a Target.

Choose the Rules pane, simplify it with the popup Rules Specific to target

Click the Plus button at the bottom of the window.

For the Process: popup, choose the last entry - *Source files with names matching*, which allows you to enter a file glob pattern.

For Using, choose *Custom Script* and enter your script below.

Use "${INPUT_FILE_BASE}" eg:

```
$TEXTURE_TOOL -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o "${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.pvr" -f PVR "${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.png"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that before!  I'm not quite sure if I can make it do what I want, since I want to select the rule based on the *target* filetype, not the source filetype (because not all PNGs want to get compressed this way) but I appreciate the pointer.