# Dynamic Version Numbering in a Default.png

Tags: iphone, objective-c, numbers, version, photoshop

I have a Default.png which includes a version number on it. Every time I update my app, I have to change it both in the lite and full version's default.png and default@2x.png. Hassle, no?

I'm pretty sure I've been going about this the wrong way. What should I do instead? (I would like to show a version number on launch, not just nix it altogether.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Compile-Time Image Compositing

If your logo doesn't need to change other than the version number, then you can use your graphics library of choice at compile-time to refactor the png.  Pseudo code below:

#### Pseudo-Code:

```
UpdateLogo(String logoName, String version)
{
    WidgetImage MyLogo(logoName + ".png");
    MyLogo.DrawText(800, 650, version);
    MyLogo.Write(logoName + "Final.png");
}

UpdateLogo("Logo.png", "Version 1.0.0");
```

Compile that program and keep it around as a custom build tool.  Then whenever you need to build your application you can compile Logo.png into LogoFinal.png.  If you need help using XCode or other tools to generate image files I suggest you search for image manipulation tools separately from "dynamic versioning".

Ideally your version string will use constants defined in an easily-editable table or controlled by your build system.  At the very least it will save you from opening up Photoshop every time you need to build your app.

### For Display in a Running Application

You should be using a font to draw the version number on top of the logo.  Then you can just include a resource file that is text-based and can be easily updated by automated tools for each build.

### Sources

- [Can you create custom build rules for XCode based on file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823392/can-you-create-custom-build-rules-for-xcode-based-on-file-type)

Comment: If it’s just displayed on the Default.png, and the application immediately goes from that to its actual UI, there’s no time (and no API) to display “a font” over the launch image.

Comment: True - looks like Xen will need to employ some scripting to update the image - I'll update my answer to take that into account.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for - a simple program to add the version number to the image automatically. Ideally it would make sure the version number matched when the new version is first compiled, but that's probably beyond me at this point. +1.

Comment: Your script could save the version number it has written to Default.png in a text file, and then read the text file before rebuilding Default.png to see if the version number has changed (to shorten build times.)

Comment: Yes - that's what I do for real projects - only build the target file if the configuration file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines say that the Default.png shouldn't be used as a splash screen; it should represent all of the UI controls the application will show, but without any localizable text or content.  (Think of how the the built-in apps like iPod and Contacts behave.)

If you're doing it for a client and they demand it, you can always use the "But the app store might reject it for violating their terms!" argument.

Of course, this doesn't apply if you're not submitting to the Store or if you just don't care.  :)

A technical add-on for the people posting above: make sure that any png compositing you're adding to the build process runs before `pngcrush` executes, so that you're not replacing an optimized image with a script-generated (and likely unoptimized) one.  You may also run into weird issues if you try doing it after `pngcrush` runs (it not displaying), anyway.

Comment: I'm curious as to where you found this - Almost every single app on the app store has a logo/splash screen not equal to the UI.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW25

Comment: also @ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5

Comment: (in the pdf these are pages 64 and 157)

Comment: Okay, so they are really meant to be guidelines, not rules. "**In general,** try to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately."

Comment: My launch is limited to about 2-3 seconds, so I think it's acceptable to display an about-like page instead.